# Create a range slider for a date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, rangeslider

I'm trying to create a range filter but for a date. The below code works fine for the columns which are integers, but I'm having trouble making it work for a date. I'm using [ion range slider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/) but am not tied to it as an option.

Kindly note that my actual data pulls a real date format in from a dataset, but for the sake of this example, I'm just using this.

Appreciate any help!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--Plugin CSS file with desired skin-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>



    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> -->

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">
                        <h4>Age Filter</h4>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="js-input-from" id="min" name="min" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px;"><input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="js-input-to" id="max" name="max" value="0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
            var max = parseInt($('#max').val(), 10);
            var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0; // use data for the age column

            if ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
                (isNaN(min) && age <= max) ||
                (min <= age && isNaN(max)) ||
                (min <= age && age <= max)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#min, #max').keyup(function () {
            table.draw();
        });
    });


    // Ion Range Slider - 
    var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
        $inputFrom = $(".js-input-from"),
        $inputTo = $(".js-input-to"),
        instance,
        min = 10,
        max = 70,
        from = 0,
        to = 0;

    $range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double", min: min, max: max,
        onStart: updateInputs,
        onChange: updateInputs,
        onFinish: updateInputs
    });
    instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");

    function updateInputs(data) {
        from = data.from;
        to = data.to;
        $inputFrom.prop("value", from);
        $inputTo.prop("value", to);

        // Force keyup event to run min max event handler
        $('#min').trigger('keyup');
    }

    $inputFrom.on("input", function () {
        var val = $(this).prop("value");
        // validate
        if (val < min) {
            val = min;
        } else if (val > to) {
            val = to;
        }
        instance.update({
            from: val
        });
    });

    $inputTo.on("input", function () {
        var val = $(this).prop("value");
        // validate
        if (val < from) {
            val = from;
        } else if (val > max) {
            val = max;
        }
        instance.update({
            to: val
        });
    });
```